# Python selenium WhatsApp bot

Tags: python, selenium, bots, whatsapp

I am trying to create a bot in WhatsApp but I keep running into
`NoSuchElementException`
My code is below :

```
from selenium import webdriver
Import time

Firefox_browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/usr/bin/geckodriver")
Firefox_browser.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')

time.sleep(15)

firefox_browser.switch_to_frame(firefox_browser.find_element_by_name("WhatsAppBot"))
firefox_browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@title="WhatsAppBot"]).click()
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no element with `name` attribute equals `WhatsAppBot` on that page

Comment: i'm new to python, so i request some help ASAP

Comment: No, I will not do your work for you. Especially when I have no idea what do you want to do here.

Comment: i wanna build a whatsapp bot that will respond to my recent chat

Comment: the whatsapp bot will be built with python and selenium

Comment: Great! Just do it

Comment: wow!How useful you are, just like a Prophet

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer has already pointed out, what you are trying to do in the last two lines does not make sense. The find element by xpath/name function expects to be pointed at a certain element on Whatsapp. There is no element called "WhatsAppBot" on the WhatsApp webpage.

Unfortunately you did not give a lot of info to work with, however, I think what you want to achieve might be similar to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUibgAsxjjc&ab_channel=VikasJha-AnIndianTechy) tutorial. I used this myself when I tried to play around with sending automatic messages via Whatsapp.

The following code is what I used for my own small bot and largely follows the before mentioned tutorial:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


# SPECIFY PATH FOR CHROME DRIVER HERE
driverPath = 'D:chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe'
# SPECIFY PATH FOR USER DIRECTORY (just change "TEST" to your WIN10 username)
userPath = "--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\TEST\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data"
# SPECIFY MESSAGES HERE
messages = ["Testmessage 1", "Testmessage 2"]


# bypass QR code login after first login
options = Options()
options.add_argument(userPath)
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverPath, options=options)

# open specified whatsapp chat
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com')
time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@title='INSERT NAME OF CHAT HERE']").click()

# Send message
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]').send_keys(messages[0])
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/button').click()
driver.close()
```

Note that this code uses the chrome driver instead.

In the future the whatsapp layout might change, meaning the given xpaths could produce errors similar to yours because the element arrangement has changed. In that case you will need to find the new xpath of the element you want to perform tasks on (i.e. click on it) and update it in your code. You can easily do that by pressing F12 while you are on Whatsapp Web, then hit Ctrl + Shift + C and click on the element. The element is then highlighted on the right of the screen and if you right click on it you will see the option "copy -> copy xpath". That's the path you will need to paste into the find_element_by_xpath function for it to work.